# Difference between Processing and Preprocessing

Tags: brain, memory

In the wikipedia article of [emotion lateralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_lateralization#:%7E:text=The%20two%20hemispheres%20have%20a,of%20different%20aspects%20of%20emotion.&text=The%20right%20amygdala%20plays%20a,the%20processing%20of%20conscious%20emotions.) it is mentioned:

> The right hemisphere is important for processing primary emotions such as fear while the left hemisphere is important for preprocessing social emotions

So I am wondering what exactly processing and preprocessing mean? What happens in preprocessing that they use this distinct word instead of mere processing?

Comment: They cite a source for that sentence, you'd have to go there. They probably talk about some later step that they think of as "true" processing, but there is no standard neuroscience answer to your question.

Comment: @BryanKrause you mention that they "think", so is it not well established?

Comment: I take it to be purely their opinion and narrative description. It does not have other meaning unless they define it.